# Is it possible to terminate FFC/FPC by hand?

Tags: ffc

Given (for example) a [15cm long ribbon of 12 conductors at 0.5mm pitch](http://www.uxcell.com/flexible-flat-cable-pin-05mm-pitch-150mm-fpc-ffc-ribbon-cable-20pcsa-type-p-1617746.html), could I cut it in half and scrape the cut ends with a razor blade or something to produce two shorter but usable ribbons? What's the best/correct way to do this? References to guides/tools for this task/etc are welcome

[image: picture of 12 pin, 15cm ffc]

Comment: is your question abour cutting the ribbon cable in half lengthwise or is your question about scraping the conductors at the ends? ... those two are not related in any way

Comment: Yes, a typical flat ribbon cable (not plastic laminate flex cable) can be cut and stripped like any old wire.

Comment: Is your motivation to save money?

Comment: It would be nice to save money but also for my application 15 cm is more than I need, and is going to be an awkward length of cable to fold out of the way

Comment: @Kietz Any chance you can share the datasheet or picture of that ribbon cable? What type of electrical connection are going on there?

Comment: @Cisco25 this is the ribbon I'm working with http://www.uxcell.com/flexible-flat-cable-pin-05mm-pitch-150mm-fpc-ffc-ribbon-cable-20pcsa-type-p-1617746.html

Comment: @Kietz It does seem that you can do what you say in your original question, have you tried it in the end?